# Extra space in listings before column character with french language

Tags: listings, babel-french

It seems that `linstings` package maintain babel language properties while it includes code. My problem is that the french space before column remains in the python code I included.

[image: example]

My question is: how do I fix it without using `\selectlanguage{english}` when I want to include code with `lstlisting` ?

Here I provide MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \selectlanguage{french}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption= Example with \texttt{\textbackslash selectlanguage\{french\}}, showspaces=true]
x = 42
if x < 0:
    x = 0
    print('Nombre négatif changé en 0')
elif x == 0:
    print('Zéro')
    \end{lstlisting}

    {\selectlanguage{english}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption= Example with \texttt{\textbackslash selectlanguage\{english\}}, showspaces=true]
x = 42
if x < 0:
    x = 0
    print('Nombre négatif changé en 0')
elif x == 0:
    print('Zéro')
    \end{lstlisting}}
\end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly is `column character` in this context? Note that I'd probably not add sapces in front of `\begin\end{lstlisting}`

Comment: If I run your example through `lualatex` (TeXLIve 2021) I get the same output in both examples. The marking of the four spaces come from the four spaces before `\end{lstlisting}`

Comment: with lualatex there is no problem, with xelatex you could (in a current tex system) use `\AddToHook{env/lstlisting/begin}{\selectlanguage{english}}`  to switch to english automatically at every listing.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer that is exactly what I was looking for because I am using xelatex to compile. Please, can you answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with lualatex there is no problem, with xelatex you could (in a current tex system) use

```
 \AddToHook{env/lstlisting/begin}{\selectlanguage{english}}
```

to switch to english automatically at every listing.